# Slide out tab jquery working with an a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-tabs

I have a slide out tab on the right of a webpage what I want to do is have an a link on the page that will make the slider open across the screen can anyone here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".pull_feedback").toggle(function(){
            jQuery("#feedback").animate({right:"-0px"});
            return false;
        },
        function(){
            jQuery("#feedback").animate({right:"-800px"});  
            return false;
        }
    ); //toggle
}); //document.ready
```

How would I run the slide out function with an a link.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Give the link a class `pull_feedback` this way:

```
<a href="#" class="pull_feedback">Pull Out</a>
```

And place this anywhere! :) Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Only one issue is I have to click the a link twice for it to do the function any idea why :)

Comment: Give a `style="display: none;"` for the `#feedback` div. :)